# SQL Server 2016 capped at specific CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a situation where my SQL server is capped at a constant CPU usage rate (13%) 
and only four cores are being utilized[image: CPU].

There is no resource governors or anything like that in place.[image]

This runs on VMWare environment.
SQL Server 2016
Windows 2016

[image: cpu cap]

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is related to this issue https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4801/sql-server-does-not-use-all-assigned-cpus-on-vm/

Comment: If you're using VMware, you'll need to change `Cores per socket` to 8 so that you have 4 sockets. [This post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204211/37801) outlines how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard Edition is limited to 4 sockets or 24 cores

Comment: Perhaps the solution is to change the  VMWare config so that it's not a 1-to-1 mapping between sockets and cores.

Comment: Yes that should work, up to 24 cores obvs. Otherwise upgrade to Enterprise Edition